# Mean of consecutive days without selling

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to calculate the mean of Interval without selling of a product.

I thought that a good way to get this is:

Count (Days without selling) / Count (Intervals of consecutive days without selling)

```
     Units Sold
0       1
1       4
2       0
3       0
4       0
5       7
6       0
7       0
8       0
9       0
10      1
11      0
```

In this example I had:

- 8 days without selling
- 3 Intervals of consecutive days without selling

So, `8/3 = 2.7` should be my result.

Counting days with No units sold I am using this:

```
x['Units Sold'] == 0).sum()
```

However, I don't figured out a good approach to calculate 'Intervals of consecutive days without selling' in a efficient way (considering I will run on multiple products)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach using `nunique`

```
s = df["Units Sold"].eq(0)

d = s.sum()
i = s[s].index.to_series().diff().ne(1).cumsum().nunique()

final = d/i # 2.6666666666666665
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `eq`, `cumsum` and `diff`

First we use `eq(0)` and `sum`, to count the amount of days where nothing was sold.

Then we get the `cumsum` of these days and check wether or not there's a difference between the rows. If this difference is `0`, that means there was an interval.

```
days = x['Units Sold'].eq(0).sum()

intervals = x['Units Sold'].eq(0).cumsum().diff().eq(0)
mask = x['Units Sold'].shift(-1).eq(0)

days / (intervals & mask).sum()
```

**Output**

```
2.6666666666666665
```

Comment: I think this also doesn't work with `[1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,]` :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.eq(0).sum()/((df.eq(0)&df.shift().ne(0)).sum())
```

Output:

```
Units Solds    2.666667
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Works for the example, but doesn't look generic - Try with `[1,
       4,
       0,
       0,
       0,
       7,
       0,
      0,
       0,
      0,
      1,
      0,
 1,
 1,]`

Comment: You are right, I update my solution. I think now is correct!

Answer (score 1):

You already knew how to get sum of count of `0`, so try this to find number of consective group of `0`

```
s = df['Units Sold'].eq(0)
(s & ~s.shift(fill_value=False)).sum()

Out[567]: 3
```